# Exit from the udevadm monitor

Tags: udev

I can't figure out how to quit the udevadm monitor.

I tried typing `exit` and `quit`. I hit keys like e, q and ESC, but it still keeps going.

I could just close the terminal window, but I like to know how to do this properly.

Comment: How about `CTRL + C`?

Comment: That does the trick, thanks. :-) 
@eblock Could you change your comment to an answer, so I can mark the question as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CTRL + C` sends a [SIGINT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)) to the terminal, stopping the current process.